# How to run only tests on a Tycho build RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

Is it possible to run only the junit Plugin tests with tycho surefire without rebuilding the application.
A little more information
We have 2 jenkins jobs.

1. builds the application (works fine).
2. should only run the tests on the already build application

I tried "mvn org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:1.0.0:test"
but fails:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:1.0.0:test (default-cli) on project com.somename.studio.template.tests: Execution default-cli of goal org.e
clipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:1.0.0:test failed: Tycho build extension not configured for MavenProject: com.somename.studio:com.somename.studio.template.tests:1.0.0-SNAPSH
OT @ C:\GIT\somename\tests\junit\com.somename.studio.template.tests.polyglot.build.properties -> [Help 1]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since tycho is correctly using the maven lifecycle, you should not use `mvn org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:1.0.0:test` but simply `mvn test` on the test project.